# Encountering ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression when using CASE - IN statements in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00979

This works:

```
 SELECT (CASE
             WHEN x = 'value' THEN
              a.col1
             ELSE
              nvl(a.col1, a.col2)
           END)
      FROM table1 a
     WHERE a.this = 'that'
     GROUP BY (CASE
                WHEN x = 'value'  THEN
                 a.col1
                ELSE
                 nvl(a.col1, a.col2)
              END)
```

But trying to have the case statement do an IN statement(trying for a more dynamic sql here),  the following code results to an **ORA-00979** error.

```
SELECT (CASE
         WHEN x IN (SELECT me FROM here WHERE this = 'example') THEN
          a.col1
         ELSE
          nvl(a.col1, a.col2)
       END)
  FROM table1 a
 WHERE a.this = 'that'
 GROUP BY (CASE
            WHEN x IN (SELECT me FROM here WHERE this = 'example') THEN
             a.col1
            ELSE
             nvl(a.col1, a.col2)
          END)
```

Is it possible to make this work or have an alternative? Thanks.
--Jonas

**Benoit**: Here's a modified sql based on your sql that recreates the error:

```
select (case when a.y IN (select 'A'||ROWNUM from dual where rownum=1) then 1 else 0 end)
from (SELECT 'A'||ROWNUM y, 'B' x FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 3) a where x = 'B'
group by (case when a.y IN (select 'A'||ROWNUM from dual where rownum=1) then 1 else 0 end)
;
```

Basically what was missing was that the FROM table should have more than one values and that a column was referenced in the CASE statement.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Forgot to add. We are using Oracle 10g

Comment: Your last select works on Oracle 11gR2, not on v9.

Comment: Thanks Benoit, for confirming that it works in 11g. Unfortunately we're stuck on 10g, I hope to find a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this error with following request (working):

```
select (case when 'X' IN (select dummy from dual where rownum=1) then 1 else 0 end)
from dual
where dummy = 'X'
group by (case when 'X' IN (select dummy from dual where rownum=1) then 1 else 0 end)
;
```

Try:

```
WITH table1_extended AS (
   SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN x IN .... END "condition"
     FROM table1 a
)
SELECT b."condition"
  FROM table1_extended b
 WHERE b.this = 'that'
 GROUP BY b."condition"
```

Comment: interesting. Indeed the dummy test works. I shall look more into my selects and try to have a more accurate dummy sql. For now an upvote for you my good sir.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have tested it on a 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 64bit AS WELL AS on a 9.2.0.6.0.

Comment: Benoit, I put in an edit that should replicate what I'm seeing. Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't the WITH syntax help?

Comment: Took a lot of work, but yes. It was a good starting point for the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't move the subselect into a join? From your adjusted version on @Benoit's test case you could do:

```
select case when a.y = b.z then 1 else 0 end, count(*)
from (select 'A'||rownum y, 'B' x from dual connect by rownum <= 3) a,
    (select 'A'||rownum z from dual where rownum=1) b
where a.x = 'B'
group by case when a.y = b.z then 1 else 0 end;
```

Which gives (in 10g):

```
CASEWHENA.Y=B.ZTHEN1ELSE0END COUNT(*)               
---------------------------- ---------------------- 
1                            1                      
0                            2
```

Not entirely convinced that will give the answer you want, but hard to tell as it's so simplified, and might be a starting point.

---

**Edit** Seems this is indeed too simplistic. Another possible solution that also looks much too simple but might do the trick is to approach this from the other end and just make the `case` in the `select` an aggregate function:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE
         WHEN x IN (SELECT me FROM here WHERE this = 'example') THEN
          a.col1
         ELSE
          nvl(a.col1, a.col2)
       END)
  FROM table1 a
 WHERE a.this = 'that'
 GROUP BY (CASE
            WHEN x IN (SELECT me FROM here WHERE this = 'example') THEN
             a.col1
            ELSE
             nvl(a.col1, a.col2)
          END)
```

Comment: your code as context, 'b' is supposedly a configuration table, so we'll be getting a Cartesian if we'll be moving the subselect into a join. Yeah the actual code is convoluted of business logic.

Comment: @jonasespelita: Cartesian joins aren't inherently bad.  If your second select always returns one row, the Cartesian result won't be any larger than the result from the query you've written and the performance should be nearly identical.

Comment: @Allan Indeed. But since in the actual production, the second select returns more than a dozen rows.. you get the idea. :) Thanks for the info.